# Popover is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code, but it is not working for me.

```
<script>
    function read_popup(f_name, l_name){
        $(".frist").popover({
            html : true, 
            content: function() {
                return $('.popup-read').html();
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<article data-placement="top" class="first" onClick="read_popup('<%= user.first_name %>','<%= user.last_name %>');">
    <a title="">                    
        <%= image_tag '/assets/web/img2.png'%>
    </a>
</article>

<!-- Pop up -->
<div class="popup-read">
    <a class="cross-btn" onClick="close_read_popup();"></a>
    <div class="title-box">ravendra kumar</div>
        <a class="btn green-btn">READ WITH ME</a><br/><br/>
        <a class="btn green-btn disable-btn">REQUEST SENT</a>  <!-- Used for disabled button -->
    </div>  <!-- End Pop up -->
```

Comment: 'It is not working' is ***never*** enough information. Why does it not work? What are you expecting to happen? What does happen? What have you tried to debug and fix? The more information you add to your question the more likely you are to receive useful help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class name is wrong at your jquery selector

change this :

```
$(".frist")
```

to :

```
$(".first")
```